# ExcelScript.PivotDateFilter interface not functioning

Tags: office-scripts

I'm trying to write an office script to select a specific date from a pivot table filter

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.pivotdatefilter?view=office-scripts

My data is formatted as a short date (yyyy-MM-dd)

This is my script

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let patchMonthSummary = workbook.getPivotTable("patchMonthSummary");

    // Get filters
    const patchMonth = patchMonthSummary.getHierarchy("Patch Month").getPivotField("Patch Month");

    // Clear filters
    patchMonth.clearAllFilters();

    // Define date
    let chosenDate: ExcelScript.FilterDatetime = {
        date: "2023-06-01",
        specificity: ExcelScript.FilterDatetimeSpecificity.day
    };

    // Apply filter
    patchMonth.applyFilter({
        dateFilter: {
            condition: ExcelScript.DateFilterCondition.equals,
            comparator: chosenDate
        }
    });
}
```

Any clues as to why this doesn't work? No selection is made. 2023-06-01 is available to manually select from the filter selection. I've attempted different conditions (eg lastmonth, which doesnt require a comparator) which also don't result in a selection being made, so my gut is that it's an issue with date formatting. If I look in the formula bar of the dates in my datasource I notice the dates are still stored in dd/MM/yyyy format, not iso

TIA

Comment: Have you tried using the macro recorder to see what code it generates?

Comment: Yes, the recorder doesn't record any interaction with pivot table filters at all. Not even the usual "this action can't be recorded yet" you get with some other actions.